# Про hover и его расстояние от родителя

Tags: css, hover

Если открывающийся меню имеет расстояние от родителя, как сделать, чтобы он "подождал" пока курсор оторвется от родителя и спуститься к нему? Ведь как только курсор отходит от родителя, hover исчезает..

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Poetry
        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
            <li>New</li>
            <li>Old</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contacts</li>
</ul>
<style>
    .drop-down-menu{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0 2.5rem 2rem 2.5rem;
        background: #f8f8f888;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
        margin-left: -4rem;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать transition-delay для этого "эффекта"

```css
.drop-down-menu{
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 2.5rem 2rem 2.5rem;
    background: #f8f8f888;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: -4rem;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0; 
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    transition-delay:1s;
}
li:hover > .drop-down-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Poetry
        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
            <li>New</li>
            <li>Old</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contacts</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.drop-down-menu{
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0 2.5rem 2rem 2.5rem;
        background: #f8f8f888;
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
        margin-left: -4rem;
        
        visibility: hidden;/* Скрываем блок */
        transition-property: visibility;/* с этим работает анимация  */
        transition-delay: 0.3s;/* время анимации */
    }
    
    .openMenu:hover .drop-down-menu { 
    visibility: visible;/* Собственно , что происходит при hover  */
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li class="openMenu">Poetry
        <ul class="drop-down-menu">
            <li>New</li>
            <li>Old</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contacts</li>
</ul>
```